# Public and Social option are not showing at leaderboard [Google Games Services]

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

i have been integrating the Games Services APIs into my game. My device language is Arabic, the problem is when i start the leaderboard activity, social and public option are not showing, but, when i change my device langauge to English or any language written in [left to right] , and restart the leaderboard activity social and public option are showing

so the problem is if my device language is Arabic, Urdu or Persian or any language written in [right to left] Social and Public option are not showing.

how can i fix this problem ?

Leaderboard : Arabic language:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Ztj.png

Leaderboard : English language:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWqdX.png

Comment: thanks for the screen shots - We'll take a look!

Comment: I've added an issue to Google plugin page:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/495
Please update in case there is a solution.